# ServiceLoader or another to dynamically load plugins

Tags: java, plugins, serviceloader

Read through

```
 http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/javase/extensible/
```

Which describes the ServiceLoader.  Fairly simple.  People that use this API, how is polling the classpath or an application path for new updates usually done?  Call the ServiceLoader.reload method every x minutes?

Or do people use other open-source APIs?  Or roll there own ServiceLoader like frames?

Comment: Take a look at this article, which describes how to use ServiceLoader with OSGi.  You may find it useful.

http://blog.osgi.org/2013/02/javautilserviceloader-in-osgi.html

Comment: @Donald W, Thanks for the osgi pointer. Interesting read.